# How to set a uniform struct in GLSL 4.6

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a group of related variables in a struct, each struct member is of basic type. I declared a uniform of that struct type, and want to use `foo.a`, `foo.b`, etc in my shader.

```c
struct Foo {
    vec3 a;
    vec4 b;
    bool c;
    mat3 d;
    uint e;
};

layout(location = 1001) uniform Foo foo;
```

The documentation says that `foo` takes up 5 uniform locations, so I assume I can simply set the uniform value like this?

```c
unsigned int e = 1;
glUniform1i(1005, e);  // e corresponds to uniform location 1005
// do sth with foo.e
```

My question is, do I have to query uniform locations explicitly here? Do I need to worry about memory layout and padding issues? My purpose of using a struct is to group these variables in a much cleaner way, but I don't want to query uniform locations explicitly.

I know it's easier to use a uniform buffer object with `std140` layout if the variables are global to all shader programs. However, since UBOs are very precious in OpenGL, I don't want to waste it here, I'd rather keep UBOs for lighting inputs. Is it possible to just use a raw uniform struct? (By *precious* I mean the number of UBOs available is relatively small compared to loose uniforms, graphics cards usually only support up to 15 or 16 UBOs)

Comment: The uniform locations are sequential and ascending

Comment: "*do I have to query uniform locations explicitly here?*" The *entire point* of allowing you to use `layout(location)` is so that you *don't* have to do that. "*since UBOs are very precious in OpenGL*" What do you mean by "precious"? Most hardware offers 14 UBO binding points *per stage*. If you use up even half of that, you're probably doing something pathological.

Comment: "*I can simply set the uniform value*" No. It is a `uint` variable, so you must match that with `gl(Program)Uniform1ui`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for pointing this out. It is indeed pathological as I realized my use of UBOs is very inefficient, for example I should have grouped all point lights in a single UBO rather than using one UBO for every light source... will change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For structures the uniform locations are sequential and ascending. See [4.4.3. Uniform Variable Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#layout-qualifiers):

> Locations can be assigned to default-block uniform arrays and structures. The first inner-most scalar, vector or matrix member or element takes the specified location and the compiler assigns the next inner-most member or element the next incremental location value.